# Add XtraReport as attachment in outlook

Tags: c#, winforms, xtrareport

This Is my code :

```
   using (RepMissingStatusProject report = new RepMissingStatusProject())
        {
            report.DataSource = await inventory.RepMissingStatusProject(Convert.ToInt32(oListProject.cmbProject.EditValue)).ConfigureAwait(true);
            report.CreateDocument();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            report.ExportToPdf(mem);
            mem.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            oMsg.To = "Test@Test.com";
            oMsg.Subject = "Test";
            oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            oMsg.Display(false); 
            oMsg.HTMLBody = "Veuillez trouver ci-joint:" + "<br />" + oMsg.HTMLBody;
            oMsg.Attachments.Add(mem, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
```

the outlook open fine and all data are correct except for the attachment file I get this error :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Member not found. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))'

How can I solve this problem?.
Thanks in advance for your help

Update:
I try to use this code

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(mem,ct);
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "État De Manque.pdf";
```

but i get another error

> System.ArgumentException
>     HResult=0x80070057
>     Message=Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again. 
>   StackTrace "at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments.Add(Object Source, Object Type, Object Position, Object DisplayName)\r\n   at Smart_Industrial_Management.PL.FrmInventory.d__44.MoveNext() in D:\SIM Windows7\Smart Industrial Management\PL\FrmInventory.cs:line 859" string

Comment: what the stacktrace of exception?

Comment: This is what i get  
StackTrace "   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments.Add(Object Source, Object Type, Object Position, Object DisplayName)\r\n   at Smart_Industrial_Management.PL.FrmInventory.<SendEmailMissingStatusProject_Click>d__44.MoveNext() in D:\\SIM Windows7\\Smart Industrial Management\\PL\\FrmInventory.cs:line 856" string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oMsg.Attachments.Add(mem`

the first argument should be the path to file on your file system.
so you need to export pdf to file (with randomly generated name) and put the path into the oMsg.Attachments.Add() method call as first argument.

so your code should be lilke

```
report.ExportToPdf(randomName);
...
oMsg.Attachments.Add(randomName,...);
File.Delete(randomName);
```

Comment: I try this solution if i use only random name without physical path it's not working and if i use it with a physical path then it work. but i do not want to save the file on my local drive I try File.Delete(randomName) but it's not work.PS:I do not send email directly from my code ,I open outlook first with all date then the user have to make the action

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah " if i use only random name without physical path" - my code was just example, you should take an approach with your specific (for example, random file name in your physical folder "\temp\random123656.eml") but NOT just copy-paste code so it should work automagically.

Comment: Yes i know. but the main problem that i don't want to save the file on my local drive and the File.Delete(physical path.randomName) doesn't work

Comment: My bad .Now it is work ,I am so sorry and thank you very much for your patience